# Show that $\mathbb{N},$ the set of natural numbers, is a locally compact metric space.

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

> Show that $\mathbb{N},$ the set of natural numbers, is a locally
>   compact metric space with the metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ for all $x$ and
>   $y$ in $\mathbb{N}.$

My attempt:

For any $n \in \mathbb{N},$ $\{ n \}$ is a neighbourhood of $n.$
        Clearly $\{ n \}$ is bounded. 
        Since $\{ n \}^c = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{n \}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N},$ we have $\{ n \}^c$ is open. 
        Therefore, $\{ n \}$ is closed in $\mathbb{N}.$
        By Heine-Borel theorem, $\{ n \}$ is compact.
        Hence, $\mathbb{N}$ is locally compact.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You mean $\{n\}$, not $\{x\}$.

Comment: fwiw: I would argue that $\{n\}$ is compact directly: any open cover definitely has an open subcover.

Comment: @EricStucky: Any hint? I fail to obtain finite open subcover from any open cover of $\{ n \}$

Comment: You shouldn't have any trouble if you try a concrete example (of an open cover, which you are trying to find a finite subcover of). If you still don't see it, feel free to state the example you're using.

Comment: @EricStucky: Suppose that $\{ n \} \subseteq \cup_{i \in I}U_i$ where $\mathcal{U} = \{U_i: i \in I\}$ is an open cover for $\{ n \}.$ There exists $i \in I$ such that $\{ n \} \subseteq U_i.$ By openness, there exists an neighbourhood $V$ of $\{ n \}$ such that $n \in V \subseteq U_i.$ $V$ is a finite open subcover for $\{ n \}.$

Comment: You don't need $V$ here, and in fact it is not a good idea to introduce it. $\{V\}$ is not a subcover of the cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$, since $V$ need not even be an element in the cover. But the idea is right, just say that the subcover is the singleton $\{U_i\}$ for your distinguished $i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are right.  You could say any finite set is compact. so any singleton set is compact.

Comment: I disagree that the proof is correct. Something that really needs to be stressed to a beginning student is that (the classical statement of) Heine-Borel *only* works in $\Bbb R^n$. It's not a difficult fix to use $\Bbb N$, but someone just learning the subject should be forced to say something about the subspace topology (or whatever you want to call it with metrics).

Comment: @EricStucky A modified version of Heine-Borel work in all metric spaces. The only alternation is that boundedness needs to be replaced by total boundedness.

Comment: The parenthetical comment was meant to inform the reader that I am, in fact, aware of the usual extension of Heine-Borel. My point stands: anyone who is inexperienced enough to have doubts about a proof like this, is almost surely inexperienced enough to need an extra sentence saying *exactly* how Heine-Borel is being used.

Comment: @EricStucky  You can't say proof is incorrect! You probably want to say maybe OP is not aware of  Heine borel 'setting space which is $R^n.$  
I myself never solve this problem like what OP did! however I think it is quite well-known that compactness does not depend on the space where set lies, OP in fact showed that $\{n\}$ is closed and bounded set in $R$ so it is compact in $R$ so it is compact in any subset of $R$ which contains $\{n\}$

Comment: I would mark it incorrect on an analysis homework where I was asking such a question, because it does not demonstrate knowledge of the hypotheses of (the classical statement of) Heine-Borel. This is the sense in which I say the proof is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The proof idea is fine, but you must also show that $d$ is indeed a metric – this is very easy, though.

Comment: I mean, it might be a nice exercise, but the problem explains that $d$ is a metric.

Comment: Okay, if we are told this, then that is fine, of course.